# Phing: Cutting out piece of code with Phing

Tags: php, phing

I tried different phing filters regex aso. to cut out different pieces of code out of a build target.

For that i use something like

```
##CUTSTART
<?php // ...code to cut... ?>
##CUTEND
```

This won't work because of no multiline support i guess:

```
             <filterchain>
   <replaceregexp>
  <regexp pattern="##CUTSTART(.*)##CUTEND" replace="## gone" ignoreCase="true" />
   </replaceregexp>
 </filterchain>
```

Got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here : http://phing.info/trac/ticket/472 It seems that multiline support has been added (4 weeks ago!)

Comment: Yes, i saw that. I updated the phing package just a few days ago over PEAR and it's not included.

Comment: The milestone of this ticket is 2.4.2, maybe you need to install this version?